# Change resolution of a windows guest to a custom value

Tags: windows, qemu, kvm, resolution

I use a Windows guest to run my MS office applications, like office Word. I typically keep MS Word fullscreen in my guest, and keep my guest's resolution at 1920x1080 (my host's resolution). However, my host has a dock and a panel, which limits the height of all windows to 988. My guest looks weird when its resolution is at 1920x1080 and the guest window is scaled down to 1920x988. How can I have a custom resolution in the Windows guest to be 1920x988?